# ruby, cucumber selenium, alert , undefined local variable or method `page'

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have a web application that when you login a pop up dialog box appears, here is what I did :

```
When /^I confirm popup$/ do
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept    
end

When /^I dismiss popup$/ do
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
end
```

I don't know where the variable page should come from , here is what I got :

```
undefined local variable or method `page' for #<Object:0x0000000003c64618> (NameError)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
When /^I confirm popup$/ do   
  driver.switch_to.alert.accept
end

When /^I dismiss popup$/ do
  driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss
end
```

More driver methods [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/3.11.0/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver#switch_to-instance_method)

Comment: Thanks Eric, now even I saw the popup dialog box, I got this error :  No modal dialog is currently open (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchAlertError)